# I am stuck with Checkbox Attribute

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I recently start to learn JavaScript and have a question about checkbox Attribute.

I want to put Nickname feature that is if someone want to put his/her nickname, he/she can check the checkbox and it appears the text box for Nickname. 
However, when the page is loaded, the text box is there even though the checkbox is not checked. 
Can anyone please help me with the problem...?

```
<fieldset>
<form>
<div>
<label for = "yesNick"> Nickname?:</label>
<input id="yesNick" name="yesNick" type="checkbox" value="yes" onchange="nicknameFunction()"/><br/>
</div>

<div id= "nick">
    <label for = "nickname">Nickname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname"><br/>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Vertify"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function nicknameFunction() {
        if (document.getElementById('yesNick').checked){
            document.getElementById('nick').style.display="inline";
            document.getElementById('nickname').setAttribute('required',true);
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('nickname').removeAttribute('required');
            document.getElementById('nick').style.display="none";
        }
        }

</script>
</form>
</fieldset>
</p>
```

Comment: Set the `div` to `display: none;`  on page load (with CSS). `<div id= "nick" style="display: none;">` or call your function `nicknameFunction` on page load to trigger the display logic.

Answer (score 4):

Set your initial display for the `#nick` div to 'none'. Your function only runs on change of the checkbox so you will need to ensure initial state on your own.

```js
   function nicknameFunction() {
        if (document.getElementById('yesNick').checked){
            document.getElementById('nick').style.display="inline";
            document.getElementById('nickname').setAttribute('required',true);
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('nickname').removeAttribute('required');
            document.getElementById('nick').style.display="none";
        }
        }
```

```css
#nick {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
<form>
<div>
<label for = "yesNick"> Nickname?:</label>
<input id="yesNick" name="yesNick" type="checkbox" value="yes" onchange="nicknameFunction()"/><br/>
</div>

<div id= "nick">
    <label for = "nickname">Nickname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname"><br/>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Vertify"/>

</form>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JavaScript for this; in fact, you shouldn't use JS for this because accessing the dom is quite slow. CSS is more than sufficient. You can also make it animated by using width instead of display property, but for my example I only used the display property.

```css
#yesNick:checked ~ #nickname {
  display: block;
}
  
#nickname {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for = "yesNick"> Nickname?:</label>
  <input id="yesNick" name="yesNick" type="checkbox" value="yes"/><br/>
  <label for = "nickname">Nickname:</label>
  <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname"><br/>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Vertify"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try hiding the textbox for the first time :

```
var nickName =  document.getElementById('nick');
nickName.style.display="none";  
  function nicknameFunction() {
        if (document.getElementById('yesNick').checked){
            nickName.style.display="inline";
            document.getElementById('nickname').setAttribute('required',true);
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('nickname').removeAttribute('required');
            nickName.style.display="none";
        }
        }
```